# adding subdomain

Tags: apache2

could you please help me. I am using apache2 under ubuntu 12.4 and i want to have subdomain like exam.domain.com. For this i have edit all the config files include hosts and enabled my sub site named exam.localhost and add this line in config file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/site/www/exam
ServerName project.localhost
 <Directory /var/www/site/www/exam>
 AllowOverride All
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
 Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`
```

when i type exam.localhost in browser it works but when i type like exam.domainname.com it's not working.
    Thank you for an help

Comment: Does your `exam.domain.com` name entry point to the IP of your server ?

Comment: `ServerName  domainname.com`
`ServerAlias *.domainname.com`

Comment: yes it point to IP address of my server and can you elaborate your coomment Gintro please. because i am new to apache2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add additional domains, or use a wildcard, you need to use ServerAlias:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site/www/exam
    ServerName project.localhost
    ServerAlias project2.localhost
    ServerAlias *.localhost
    ServerAlias project.example.com
    ServerAlias project2.example.com
    ServerAlias exam.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    <Directory /var/www/site/www/exam>
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you @cyberbill79. Now www.exam.mydomain.com opening the sub-directory site but shows the error message: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: And also in the error.log: [Fri Mar 21 13:58:06 2014] [crit] [client 173.245.54.71] configuration error:  couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!: /32-archieve/Mahapanya

Comment: Thank you all for you helpful solutions and now it's working by adding "Satisfy Any" under the line "Require all granted".